# Could not find driver (SQL: select top 1 * from [Cs].[users] where [email] = sam@gmail.com)

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I use Laravel to develop backend. PHP dll files and necessary extensions have already been added to the `.ini` file. I use Wamp and PHP version 7.4.33. This is the part of `.ini` file.

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=dba
extension=com_dotnet
;extension=enchant
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
extension=gmp
extension=intl
extension=imap
extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=phpdbg_webhelper
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

extension=soap
extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
extension=sqlite3
;extension=sysvshm
;extension=tidy
extension=xmlrpc
extension=xsl
;extension=zend_test

extension=sqlsrv_74_ts_x64
extension=pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll
```

I want to fix this issue.